# Google Map Direction routes do not disappear when the next one was come out

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the Google Maps Javascript API V3 to my Android WebView
Now I got a problum that when I use the Direction like A to B it works, but when I change that A to C, the route of A to B does not disappear, so that route A to B is overlapping route A to C.

A to B
[image: A to B]

A to C
[image: A to C]

Button to do direct

```
direction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        infowindow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        String centerUrl = "javascript:direction(" + Lat + "," + Lng + "," + LatNew + "," + LngNew + ")";
        webView.loadUrl(centerUrl);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple markers</title>
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var myLatLng,endLatLng;
    var map;
    var marker,beachMarker,eatMarker,drinkMarker;
    var location;

    function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 17,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
        beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 25.078838,lng: 121.574204},
          map: map,
          icon: 'file:///android_asset/Marker.png'
        });
        beachMarker.addListener('click',function(){
          Android.responseResult("beach");
          });

        eatMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 25.080643,lng: 121.569551},
          map: map,
          icon: 'file:///android_asset/Marker.png'
        });
        eatMarker.addListener('click',function(){
          Android.responseResult("eat");
          });

        drinkMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 25.079734,lng: 121.569519},
          map: map,
          icon: 'file:///android_asset/Marker.png'
        });
        drinkMarker.addListener('click',function(){
        Android.responseResult("drink");
          });

    }


    function centerAt(latitude,longitude){
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        marker.setMap(null);
        map.panTo(myLatLng);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: 'file:///android_asset/location.png'
        });

    }
    function direction(latitude,longitude,latitudeNew,longitudeNew){
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        endLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeNew,longitudeNew);
        directionsService.route({
        origin: myLatLng,
        destination: endLatLng,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }






</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMqm4dbVtq1OiUpyDxzRcU5196guci_jg&callback=initMap"></script>
```

What can I do to remove the last route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a global var for `directionsDisplay` and not a local one inside the direction function. Then in the direction function you should set the directionsDisplay to null and assign it to the new one.

```
<script>
var myLatLng,endLatLng;
var map;
var marker,beachMarker,eatMarker,drinkMarker;
var location;
var directionsDisplay;

function direction(latitude,longitude,latitudeNew,longitudeNew) {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    if (directionsDisplay != null) {
       directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

    .....
```